# Solve the error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, launch4j

I'm a new programmer and I'm trying to create .exe file of my project. The project works without any error or warning, I created a fat-jar of my whole project with shadowJar plugin and modifing the Run configuration I got it working fine through Intellij.

```
--module-path
"C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-17.0.7\lib"
--add-modules
javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

To create the .exe file I'm using Lauch4j but after I created the executable I couldn't run the application and the error "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" is produced.

Any help will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.
This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.0'
}

group 'com.preventivoApp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
mainClassName = 'com.appproject_preventivo.QuoteMainApplication'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.appproject_preventivo'
    mainClass = 'com.appproject_preventivo.QuoteMainApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')

    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:20'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:20'

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")

    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.15.0'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.15.0'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.15.0'

    implementation group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.28'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    mergeServiceFiles()
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.appproject_preventivo.QuoteMainApplication'
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that "shadowed" JARs (also knows as "fat" or "uber" JARs) and modules do not mix. The JAR specification does not define any way to have multiple modules per JAR file. Also, when you "double click" on an executable JAR file it gets launched via the `-jar` switch, meaning everything is placed on the class-path. Now, I don't really know how Launch4J works, but the fact you're shadowing your JAR file makes me think all the code is being placed on the class-path. And in that context, if your main class extends `Application`, then you'll see the error you'll describe.

Comment: See if creating a separate main class, which only contains a main method that does nothing but call `Application.launch(QuoteMainApplication.class, args)`, fixes the error.

Comment: As an aside, those JVM arguments in the IDE should not be necessary given you're using Gradle. You also should not need to download the JavaFX SDK because you've configured Gradle to download the JavaFX JARs from the Maven Central repository. If you aren't doing this already, your IDE should be delegating to Gradle for most, if not all, build tasks. You've applied the `application` plugin, so when you want to run your project you should be having your IDE execute the Gradle `run` task.

Comment: @Slaw I tried adding a class as you have suggested but it didn't solve the problem. I'm having issue to create a jar file that include all the library that I added. My aim is to create a .exe file (installer) that works in any computer and doesn't need any version of java installed in the system to work (like most of the program are installed). If you can give me some advice on how to do it would be very very helpful because I spent too much hours tring to find any clue on internet. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: "... My aim is to create a .exe file (installer) ..." The installer has nothing to do with the application. Its job is to copy and configure all the necessary components of your application on the respective target computer. Launch4J **does not create an installer** but a windows native launcher. Say what you really want to do, not how you decided to do it.

Comment: You can use jpackage to create an installer.  It can be used from gradle via the badass-runtime-plugin, whose git site links to JavaFX specific examples.  Read the documentation for each if you would like to know how to use them.  It does not need launch4j or shadow jars or anything like that.

Comment: a bit offtopic, but launch4j creates a launcher that effectively replaces the one generated by jpackage (which still imposes quite a few restrictions that I personally don't like).